# I expect to get an error when I close(unmout) a component that fetchs data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch

I'm learning in 'The Net Ninja' about routes and navigating between the pages.

In there a component does data fetching and if we navigate(from the Home page) to another page(New Blog), before completing fetch, it gives an error. (Can't perform a state updating over an unmounted component).

[image]

So used an `Abort Controller` and `cleanup function` to fix it (To stoping fetching after unmounting the component).

**But I don't get any error even without using from `Abort Controller` and `cleanup function`. So why?**

> 1- please navigate to New Blog

> 2- Then navigate to Home

> 3- Then Quickly navigate to New Blog again. (before loading data)

**This should give the above error.**

Is it for a different versions? In there: `RRD: 5.2.0 && react: 17.0.1` and for me: `RRD: 5.3.3 && react: 18.1.0`

It's project: https://codesandbox.io/s/complete-react-tutorial-forked-c7onv3

Comment: This error doesn't exist in the codesandbox.

Comment: @Mina Yes and my question is about the same. Why I don't get any error about state updating on unmounted components? (Fetch completes in the background, while we navigated to another page).

Comment: TL;DR This warning was removed in React 18 because it was often a false-positive and lead to anti-pattern code using an `isMounted` check. If you are attempting to cancel in-flight network requests you are on the right path.